# How to provide a web interface for a .Net application, like a router does?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, user-interface

I'm using ASP.NET in Visual Studio for Mac, Visual Studio for Mac doesn't have as much support for ASP.NET (preset templates) as Visual Studio Community, the performance isn't very good, and the main() function of the program has to run some Fixed functions let everything happen inside, all .cs files also have to be declared static, which I find inflexible. And ASP.NET's built-in design patterns are bloated compared to pure CLI programs with a lot of configuration files.

I hope to write a program similar to Syncthing, which uses a CLI program as the main body and opens a local http service. You can access the webUI program by accessing an address similar to "127.0.0.1:42900" like a home router. In this way, the CLI program can run independently without running the webUI

I wish to use Visual Studio Code

I want to be able to use all the power of the web world, such as bootstrap, Vue, ECharts, etc.

If possible, I want this solution to be cross-platform, window, linux, mac, (even android?)

I'm also not against newer versions of ASP.NET like ASP.NET Core if needed, but I'd also like to hear about other possibilities, like some kind of open source that builds a native http service in c# and handles requests and return values frame? (NancyFx has stopped development, is there a better option?)

If you mention ASP.NET Core, I hope it can be built in Visual Studio Code, and I hope you can tell me what kind of preset template or scaffolding (or related tutorial?) to use it, otherwise it will be difficult for me to dig it myself To specific practical methods...

Comment: there is a dotnet cli for asp.net core core from where you can choose template and use that

Comment: There is "kestrel" that is a standalone webserver, in contrast to running in IIS. I have not used visual studio code much, but I think there should be ASP.Net core templates available that uses kestrel by default. There is also `HttpListener`, but I suspect that will have a worse developer experience.

Comment: @JonasH

Kestrel is a good idea. I can build a webAPI program based on it. But I am afraid that this will cause the CLI program to no longer run independently from the front-end web page? Because the `Main()` function needs to continuously execute functions like `host.Run();`, so that it cannot run itself when the outside world does not send commands to itself...

Comment: I think you are looking for [Katana](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/an-overview-of-project-katana)

Answer (score -1):

According to chatGPT and everyone's answers, I currently think that I should build a CLI in .net core, <del>and then refer to asp.net's kestrel server and MVC to obtain functions such as two-way binding, and based on this, make a web API program as a backend.</del>

<del>On the front end, I might use vue.js combined with some kind of HTTP request technology to communicate with the back end.</del>

<del>And use kestrel to support the operation of the front end (although this seems superfluous).</del>

I haven't implemented this yet, but if I go ahead and do it, and if I remember, I'll explain the method I use here.

2023.4.22
Currently, I'm trying to use CLI + static page generator as UI. `CommandLineParser`